# Android: Change button insets

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following button:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3564087/button.png
However this image has a blank area on the right side, border and shadow (which doesn't exist on the right side). This means that when I insert some text on the button and set the gravity to center, the text doesn't really gets centered because the area in which i want it to be centered isn't the total area of the image.

My question is, can I set an inset Rect (the same way as you can do in iOS), in which I want to display the text? Or do I need to create a separate TextView in front of the Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can do this using 9-patch, I found that it is simpler to do it using the "padding" property of the Button view.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. Please elaborate.

Comment: The question/answer regards Android only.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating a [9 patch image](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html). It won't only allow to define a rect where the text will go, but also will allow your button to stretch to any size screen and resolution.